# Gulp minifyCss remove special comments

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-minify-css, gulp-clean-css

I am using gulp minifyCss to minify my css to reduce filesize. My gulp task looks something like this:

```
gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('styles/*.css')
    .pipe(concatCss("all.css").on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(minifyCss().on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

It works fine and output as expected. However, it does not remove special comments `/*! comment */`

How can I get minifyCss to have special comments removed?

Comment: Just an FYI `gulp-minify-css` has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) in favor of [gulp-clean-css](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should set [keepSpecialComments](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-programmatically) option:

```
gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('styles/*.css')
    .pipe(concatCss("all.css").on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(minifyCss({keepSpecialComments : 0}).on('error', standardHandler))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: As of 4.0 (clean-css), keepSpecialComments has been renamed to just: specialComments

Answer (score 1):

Now Ufuk's variant not working. Try this:

```
.pipe(cleanCSS({level: {1: {specialComments: false}}}))
```